# How to store complex data in Redis?

Tags: redis

I want to store data in the following style in Redis database:

```
 { _id: 5b3a60cdccbdf81bcc5343e6,
    id: 5b3a60cdccbdf81bcc5343e5,
    position: 'Web dveloper',
    type: 'Contract',
    Skills: 'html, bootstrap,php',
    location: 'Boston',
    job_id: 1,
    Experience: '0-6 months',
    Description: 'Developer for websites and web apps',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b3a6151ccbdf81bcc5343e8,
    id: 5b3a6151ccbdf81bcc5343e7,
    position: 'Data analyst',
    type: 'contract',
    Skills: 'big data, hadoop,python',
    location: 'boston',
    job_id: 2,
    Experience: '1yr',
    Description: 'for analysing incoming data',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b3a6207ccbdf81bcc5343ea,
    id: 5b3a6207ccbdf81bcc5343e9,
    position: 'Content Writer',
    type: 'Permanent',
    Skills: 'Technical wirtting,Custmer engagement',
    location: 'new jersey',
    job_id: 3,
    Experience: '0-6 months',
    Description: 'for writting website content',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b3a62c4ccbdf81bcc5343ec,
    id: 5b3a62c4ccbdf81bcc5343eb,
    position: 'node js specialist',
    type: 'Permanent',
    Skills: 'node js ,express js , mean stack',
    location: 'boston',
    job_id: 4,
    Experience: '1yr',
    Description: 'for the web apps',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b3a6362ccbdf81bcc5343ee,
    id: 5b3a6362ccbdf81bcc5343ed,
    position: 'database expert',
    type: 'temporary',
    Skills: 'sql , no sql, mysql,sql server,mongo db',
    location: 'boston',
    job_id: 5,
    Experience: '2 yrs',
    Description: 'for desinging and maintaing databases',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b3a8639c8323b2cfc179969,
    id: 5b3a8639c8323b2cfc179968,
    position: 'Social media manager',
    type: 'Permanent',
    Skills: 'Social media marketing,Digital marketing',
    location: 'Boston',
    job_id: 4,
    Experience: '1yr',
    Description: 'For managing company socail media accounts',
    __v: 0 }
```

I have gone through Redis official documentation but I have found nothing. Can anybody guide what structure I can use to store and how I can retrieve these data in table?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do with this data? You can store the object as a whole in a single value, or can use Redis hashes if you need to frequently access only some fields.

Answer (score 1):

One of the alternatives you could use to store your data is the [Redis Hash data](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes) structure.  Using the Redis Hash structure, you could store your entities using the id as the key, then map the remaining fields into a Redis Hash using the [HMSET command](https://redis.io/commands/hmset).

The recommended client for Node.js is the [npm Redis package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).  This will provide all of the functionality you need to interact with Redis.

Ultimately, your query patterns are going to determine the optimal structure for your data.  Using a hash is a very basic entity mapping approach to the problem, but it might not be the best way to structure the data. There may be more efficient ways to structure the data depending on how you plan to use it.

Comment: i have tried it but retrieval is a problem i am having while using as i want to retrieve all data at once and display it but i'm not getting any command for that @Tague Griffith

Comment: What are your main query patterns, that's going to determine which data structures are the best fit.  Can you list 3 or 4 of your most common queries?

Answer (score -1):

Redis doesn't offer that much structure directly, but there are layered libraries that do. I am trying to use Walrus, a Python library, that offers that capability atop Redis.

Comment: any library for node js